# A confusion about the partial limits of $F(x) = \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, riemann-integration

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich, at page 136, it is asked that

> Let $f : I_{a,b} → R$ be a continuous function defined on an interval
>   $I_{a,b} = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n | a_i ≤ x_i ≤ b_i , i = 1, . . . , n\}$,
>   and let $F : I_{a,b} → \mathbb{R}^1 $ be defined by the equality
>
> $$F(x) = \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt,$$
>
> where $I_{a,x} ⊂ I_{a,b}$. Find the partial derivatives of this
>   function with respect to the variables $x_1, . . . , x_n$.

**My work:**

Directly from the definition of partial derivative,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1 } (x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{I_{a, x'} } f(t)dt  - \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt}{ |h| },$$

where $x' = (x_1 + h, x_2, ..., x_n)$.

$$ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{I_{x,x'}} f(t)dt +  \int_{I_{a, x} } f(t)dt  - \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt}{ |h| } \\
=  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{I_{x,x'}} f(t)dt }{ |h| },$$

but $\int_{I_{x,x'}} f(t) dt = 0$ even before $h \to 0$, so the limit has to be zero, but this result is wrong clearly, so where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake lies in the assumption that$$\int_{I_{a,x'}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{I_{x,x'}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{I_{a,x}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$This would be like asserting that the area of the rectangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,2)$, and $(0,2)$ is the sum of the area of the rectangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$ with the rectangle whose vertices are $(1,1)$, $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, and $(1,2)$. (Yes, I know that they are squares.)

Comment: Because $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\int_{I_{x,x'}}f(t)\,\mathrm dt = \int_{x_1}^{x_1 + h} d_x^1 \int _{x_2}^{x_2} dx^2 .. \int_{x_n}^{x_n} f(t) dx^n$, and the inner integrals are zero because of their limit are equal.

Comment: I mean if $n = 1$, yes your example works, but when $n \not = 1$, my argument also works.

Comment: Take $n=2$, $a=(0,0)$, $f(x,y)=1$, $x=(1,1)$, and $x'=(2,1)$. Then $\int_{I_{x,x'}}f$ is the area of the rectangle whose vertices are located at $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$, and $(1,1)$; in other words, $\int_{I_{x,x'}}f=1$.

Comment: How did you get the vertices $(2,1)$ and $(2,0)$ out of $x= (1,1)$ and $x' = (1,2)$ ? $x \to x'$ is just a line in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ and it has measure zero, so the and double integral has to have a value $0$, isn't it ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas I meant $x'=(2,1)$. I've edited my comment.

Comment: I was also edited my comment actually.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I don't know what you mean when you write that “$x\to x'$ is just a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$”.

Comment: By the way, the value of $a$ is unnecessary in there because we have already cancel the integral between $a$ and $x$. This problematic part is that the integral between $x$ and $x'$ is $0$, and in this particular case, $(2,1)$ and $(1,1)$ describes a line in $\mathbb{R}^2 $, hence the area is zero.

Comment: @onurcanbektas You are right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @onurcanbektas And I am sorry for wasting your time. Also, I am glad that I could help.

Comment: it is definitely not a waste, I mean this is also a way to test my knowledge :) Plus, I remember some many cases where I wasted your time in here, so even in the worst case, we are not square yet :)